# error while using isALive() or join method

Tags: java, multithreading

I'm trying to use isALive and join method but its throwing an error like can not find symbol....please tell me where is the error exactly in this program.
and what is the use of join method.i know that it is a wait for threads to finish but i want in details.

```
class newthread1 implements Runnable {
    newthread1() {
        Thread t = new Thread(this, "FirstThread");
        System.out.println("Child Thread:" + t);
        t.start();
    }

    public void run() {
        System.out.println("We are in processing for 1st thread");
        int p = 1000, t = 3;
        double r = 3.5, si;
        try {
            si = (p * r * t) / 100;
            System.out.println("Simple Interest:" + si);
        } catch (ArithmeticException e) {
            System.out.println("Error:" + e);
        }
    }
}

class newthread2 implements Runnable {

    newthread2() {
        Thread t = new Thread(this, "SecondThread");
        System.out.println("Child Thread:" + t);
        t.start();
    }

    public void run() {
        try {
            System.out.println("We are in processing for 2nd thread");
            double a, r = 4.3;
            int p = 1000, n = 3;
            double temp = Math.pow((1 + r / 100), n);
            a = temp * p;
            System.out.println("Compound interest:" + a);
        } catch (ArithmeticException e) {
            System.out.println("Error:" + e);
        }
    }
}

class mainthread {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        newthread1 t11 = new newthread1();
        new newthread2();
        boolean b = t1.t.isAlive();
        System.out.println("Thread is alive:" + b);
        t1.t.join();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

**Solution 1** 

Change your main method as

```
class mainthread {
    public static void main(final String args[]) throws InterruptedException {
        Thread thread = new Thread(new newthread1());
        newthread1 t11 = new newthread1();
        new newthread2();
        boolean b = thread.isAlive();
        System.out.println("Thread is alive:" + b);
        thread.join();
    }
}
```

and to run a thread call `thread.start()`, creating an instnace of an runnable object will not automatically start running. You explicitly tell thread to start or stop.

**Solution 2** 

or you can create Thread object `'t'` as `global varibable` and change class as

```
class newthread1 implements Runnable {
    public Thread t;

    newthread1() {
        t = new Thread(this, "FirstThread");
        System.out.println("Child Thread:" + t);
        t.start();
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        System.out.println("We are in processing for 1st thread");
        int p = 1000, t = 3;
        double r = 3.5, si;
        try {
            si = p * r * t / 100;
            System.out.println("Simple Interest:" + si);
        } catch (ArithmeticException e) {
            System.out.println("Error:" + e);
        }
    }

    public Thread getT() {
        return t;
    }
}
```

and then main method as

```
class mainthread {
    public static void main(final String args[]) throws InterruptedException {
        newthread1 t11 = new newthread1();
        new newthread2();
        boolean b = t11.t.isAlive();
        System.out.println("Thread is alive:" + b);
        t11.t.join();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I personally advice you to first take a tutorial regarding basics of Java. I was convinced that you are not clear about basic Java from the following:

```
boolean b=t1.t.isAlive();
```

You don't have a varibale named defined as `t1` and still you try to use it.

The compiler won't find any variable named `t1` and it will complain `Cannot find symbol t1`

I think you wanted to use `t11`.

Also even if you use `t11` it will still complain because you don't have `t` as a class variable in your class `newthread1`, instead you have defined a local variable inside the constructor

Also try to read some java standards like how to declare a class, naming conventions, etc.

It will help you a lot in future.

Comment: As I said in comment to @TheNewIdiot, there's no `t` field to use, so even if doing that change, the code won't compile.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza I added that to my answer with short description

Answer (score 1):

First error , You have defined the reference variable as `t11` :

```
 newthread1 t11=new newthread1();
```

Hence use `t11` in your code:

```
boolean b=t11.t.isAlive(); // change t1 to t11
```

Secondly , there is no `Thread t` instance variable defined in `newthread1` or `newthread2` classes. This might help :

```
class newthread1 implements Runnable{
  Thread t; // make this an instance variable , currently it is local to constructor
  newthread1()
 {
   t=new Thread(this,"FirstThread");
   System.out.println("Child Thread:"+t);
   t.start();
 }
```

Comment: I can't see a `t` field nor in `newthread1` nor in `newthread2` either.

Answer (score 1):

To create a thread in java there are [two ways](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/runthread.html)
1.By implementing `Runnable` interface.
2.By extending `Thread` class.

**If you implement `Runnable` interface then you need to pass `Runnable` object to the `Thread`

constructor**.
So that your object will get Thread behavior.

**If you extends `Thread` class then you need create object of your `Thread` extended class**.
So that your object will get Thread behavior.

But you have not followed any of the above two ways,

In your code the statement `newthread1 t11 = new newthread1();` creates only simple object
not the `Thread object`.
But your trying to invoke `Thread` methods on `normal object` that leads to compilation errors.

To avoid errors you need to follow any one of above two ways.
More specific you have to
 replace `newthread1 t11 = new newthread1();`  with this statement

```
 Thread thread = new Thread(new newthread1());//first way implements Runnable
```

or replace `class newthread1 implements Runnable{` with this statement

```
class newthread1 extends Thread implements Runnable{//second way extends Thread
```

Answer (score 0):

> I'm trying to use isALive

There is no such method. Do you mean `isAlive()`?

> and join method but its throwing an error like can not find symbol

That's a compile error, probably because of the mis-spelling. Compile errors are printed, not 'thrown'.

> please tell me where is the error exactly in this program.

The compiler has already done that, and you haven't posted it here. If you're expecting someone else to recompile your program for you just to find the error site, I suggest you may have a long wait.

> and what is the use of join method.i know that it is a wait for threads to finish but i want in details.

The details are to be found in the [Javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#join%28%29). I could quote it here but frankly I can't see the point when you should already have read it. If there was something there you didn't understand, you should have said so in your question.